# How to access array after using for loop to assign values

Tags: java, arrays

After using a for loop to assign values to the char array, how do I access those values outside of the for loop? Because i need to manipulate the values later, to remove duplicates ones. Thank you for any help. Much appreciated.

```
public static void processLine(File input, File output) throws FileNotFoundException{ 
Scanner i = new Scanner(input);
PrintStream o = new PrintStream(output);
while(i.hasNextLine()){
    String text = i.nextLine();      
    char[] pos = new char[text.length()];
    for (int x = 0; x < text.length();x++){
        pos[x] = text.charAt(x);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Declare the array outside of the loop

Comment: @user3580294 it **IS** outside of the **for** loop

Comment: Do you not mean outside while loop?

Comment: @blgt I was more thinking the `while` loop...

Comment: if it is outside the while loop, how do determine the length of the string to know the size of array needed?

Comment: You can declare the array separately of actually creating it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said before by   user3580294, just store you datas by declaring a structure befor performing the loop. Then inside the loop you store the datas, and after the loop you can enjoy it and use it!

```
public static void processLine(File input, File output) throws FileNotFoundException{ 
        Scanner i = new Scanner(input);
        PrintStream o = new PrintStream(output);

        ArrayList<String> saved= new ArrayList<String>();

        while(i.hasNextLine()){
            String text = i.nextLine();      
            char[] pos = new char[text.length()];
            for (int x = 0; x < text.length();x++){
                pos[x] = text.charAt(x);
            }

            saved.add(text);
        }


        // you can use "saved" here ! :) but this code can be shorter I think
    }
```

You might delete this step :

```
for (int x = 0; x < text.length();x++){
                pos[x] = text.charAt(x);
```

And replace it with :

```
saved.add(text);
```

Final result should be :

```
public static void processLine(File input, File output) throws FileNotFoundException{ 
    Scanner i = new Scanner(input);
    PrintStream o = new PrintStream(output);

    ArrayList<String> saved= new ArrayList<String>();

    while(i.hasNextLine()){
        String text = i.nextLine();                 
        saved.add(text);
    }


    // you can use "saved" here ! :) enjoy
}
```